# How can I detect the entry file in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

How can I detect the entry file in Node.js?

For example, if I launch my application by typing `node file1.js`, how can I tell that **file1.js** was the entry point?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can also use `require.main`.

> Accessing the main module
>   When a file is run directly from Node,
>   require.main is set to its module. That means that you can determine
>   whether a file has been run directly by testing
>
> require.main === module
>
> For a file foo.js, this will be true if run
>   via node foo.js, but false if run by require('./foo').
>
> Because module provides a filename property (normally equivalent to
>   __filename), the entry point of the current application can be obtained by checking require.main.filename.

[hot sauce](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_accessing_the_main_module)

Answer (score 6):

`process.argv[1]` provides that information.

Comment: You've made me laugh. I should have known this. Thank you. :)

Comment: In 2023 this should be the accepted answer, if you attempt to access `require.main` in a project using es modules, you'll encounter the error `ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead`